# How can I upload a image to WordPress REST API from react app

Tags: javascript, wordpress, create-react-app, wordpress-rest-api

I am working a react app, I am using WordPress API and all is working well, but need to upload a image via wp-json/wp/v2/media

But I have no idea how to do it, I don't know which headers and data use.

The code is:

```
  uploadImage(masterFile) {
  const file = masterFile[0];

  const { mediaUrl } = this.state;
  var self = this;
  let host = this.props.host + mediaUrl;
  this.setState({
    showOverlay: true,
    overlayMsg: "Wait Upload the image..."
  });
  let user = cookie.load("user");
  const myHeaders = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + user.token,
    "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename=/"' + file.name + '/"',
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
  };

  let data = {

  };

  axios
    .post(host, data, { headers: myHeaders })
    .then(function(response) {
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
  
    })
    .then(function() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to install a Wordpress plugin to generate a token allowing you to do JWT authentication to the Wordpress Rest API.**

Here is a **plugin** doing that, and there's a documentation attached detailing the configuration you have to do on the wordpress server:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Here is an **example** of JS code using JWT authentication, to upload an image on Wordpress:
https://gist.github.com/RubenPauwels1/db52705ffa0ef36b7a39407a463d9e93